# Why is my extension showing other extensions when using magento 2.0 connect to upload it?

Tags: module, magento

Why does my extension show these other extensions when using magento connect before preceding with the install? BTW, my is the Beckin_DropDownShipping extension.

community   Beckin_DropDownShipping     1.2.0 (stable)  Ready to install

community   Mage_Core_Modules   1.7.0.2 (stable)    Already installed

community   Lib_Varien  1.7.0.0 (stable)    Already installed

community   Lib_Google_Checkout     1.5.0.0 (stable)    Already installed

community   Lib_Js_Calendar     1.51.1.1 (stable)   Already installed

community   Lib_Js_Mage     1.7.0.1 (stable)    Already installed

community   Lib_Phpseclib   1.5.0.0 (stable)    Already installed

community   Mage_Locale_en_US   1.7.0.1 (stable)    Already installed

community   Lib_Mage    1.7.0.1 (stable)    Already installed

community   Lib_ZF  1.11.1.0 (stable)   Already installed

community   Lib_Js_Prototype    1.7.0.0.3 (stable)  Already installed

community   Lib_ZF_Locale   1.11.1.0 (stable)   Already installed

This is my dependencies that I have setup in the package file.

```
<dependencies>
<required>
<php><min>5.1.0</min><max>6.0.0</max></php>
<package>
<name>Mage_Core_Modules</name>
<channel>community</channel>
<min>1.6.0.0</min><max>1.7.0.2</max>
</package>
</required>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I removed all the dependencies except for the php versions and now the extension does not pull up the other modules :)

Answer (score 0):

Magento Connect offers the ability to update Magento itself via Magento Connect.  The 11 packages

```
Lib_Google_Checkout
Lib_Js_Calendar
Lib_Js_Mage
Lib_Js_Prototype
Lib_Mage
Lib_Phpseclib
Lib_Varien
Lib_ZF
Lib_ZF_Locale
Mage_Core_Modules
Mage_Locale_en_US
```

are the base needed for a Magento installation.

Keep in mind Magento 2 is still be actively worked on and is in beta.  That's a **hard** beta, not a Googley beta.  If you attempt to update those 11 base modules via connect, it looks like you'll install an older version of Magento on top of Magento 2.  This would make Bad Things™ happen.

Comment: Thanks! So is there any way to fix that? Is that b/c of my extension?

Comment: I have updated above the dependencies that are setup in the package file. That is the basic info for the dependencies that I seen on how to package the extension. Again, is those other packages loading b/c of my extension? Should I do something to stop that?

Comment: I doubt eBay has packages yet for Magento 2, i wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks! Not sure what you are talking about with eBay. This is not an ebay extension although the name can be confusing LOL Thanks to you I was able to find out that is was the dependencies that I had set. I removed all of them except for the php versions and it no longer pulls up the other modules.

Comment: eBay owns Magento and controls its development.

Comment: Oh ok kewl, I didn't know that.